# AWS Aurora MySQL Database cloning using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I want to create a copy of my production aurora mysql database on a weekly basis. The copies will be used for development.

I like the clone feature of Aurora MySQL but unfortunately, the instructions to create these clones from AWS CLI are not clear.

Following the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html#Aurora.Managing.Clone.CLI), I am able to create another Aurora cluster, but it doesn't create the DBs. It just creates an empty cluster. I am not able to figure out the commands to create a new Db inside this cluster from a snapshot of the Db in the source cluster as the restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot is [not supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot.html#restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot) for Aurora MySQL.

Please let me know the commands to clone the Aurora Cluster along with the DBs inside it.

Comment: @MarkB I am using this command 
   
    `aws rds restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time \
        --source-db-cluster-identifier arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:AAAAAAAAAAA:cluster:BBBBBBBBBB-cluster \
        --db-cluster-identifier YYYYYYYYYY-cluster \
        --restore-type copy-on-write \
        --use-latest-restorable-time`

Comment: Yes, I checked after the cluster was marked available. The document mentions that it will NOT create the DBs. My question is then how do we clone the databases? Cloning an empty cluster is not helpful without the DBs in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time.html), this is a two phase process.

When you create a new cluster with:

```
aws rds restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time \ 
  --source-db-cluster-identifier arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:AAAAAAAAAAA:cluster:BBBBBBBBBB-cluster \ 
  --db-cluster-identifier YYYYYYYYYY-cluster \ 
  --restore-type copy-on-write \ 
  --use-latest-restorable-time
```

When this completes, data store has been created and is ready to be used but there are no aurora instances running.

The second step would be to create one (or more) instances:

```
aws rds create-db-instance \
  --db-cluster-identifier YYYYYYYYYY-cluster \ 
  --db-instance-class <value> \
  --engine <value>
  (other optional values)
```

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and this need to create a database instance is the reason for my post. I want to clone the production cluster and then use the database in it for development purpose. Creating an empty database defeats this purpose.

Comment: @SmrutiMandal that isn't what this does.  The cloned data is on the cluster, which begins with an instance count of 0, so the second step brings the instance count for the cluster to 1.  Aurora DB Instances do not have storage -- the storage is entirely in the cluster, but only accessible via the instances.  The console hides this complexity but the CLI allows/requires access to the underlying processes.

Comment: Also you appear to be confusing the terms "database" (content) and "database instance" (virtual machine).

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot I really was confusing the content of the database with the database instance. I wish there was a way to mark your comment as answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of Aurora DB cloning took me a while to get my head around. With Aurora the data is actually part of the cluster. The database instance gets its data from the cluster. To clone one Aurora cluster to another you need to clone the cluster, then create a DB instance in the new cluster. The db instance you create in the new cluster will get its data from the cluster in which it is created. Phew! That was a long explanation.  Anyway the shell script below is something I run from a cron and it works for me (so far). The security group ids below are fake for this example obviously.

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date +%s)
NOW_DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
SOURCE_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID=source-aurora-cluster
TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID=target-aurora-cluster
TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_CLASS=db.r3.large
TARGET_ENGINE="aurora-mysql"
NEW_MASTER_PASS=setyourpasshere
SECURITY_GROUP_ID=sg-0cbc97f44ed74d652
SECURITY_GROUP_ID_DEV=sg-0b36b590347ba8796
SECURITY_GROUP_ID_ADMIN=sg-04032188f428031fd
BACKUP_RETENTION=7


echo -e "\e[93mDeleting existing RDS instance ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} ..."
aws rds delete-db-instance --db-instance-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --skip-final-snapshot
echo -e "\e[93mWaiting for database deletion to complete..."
sleep 10
aws rds wait db-instance-deleted --db-instance-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID
echo -e "\e[92mFinished deleting old ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} RDS instance."

EXISTING_CLUSTER_INSTANCE=$(aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --query 'DBInstances[0].[DBInstanceIdentifier]' --output text)

echo -e "\e[93mDeleting existing cluster instance ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} ..."
aws rds delete-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --skip-final-snapshot
echo -e "\e[93mWaiting for cluster deletion to complete..."

status="available"
while [ "$status" == "available" ] || [ "$status" == "deleting" ]; do
    sleep 10
    status=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --query "*[].{DBClusters:Status}" --output text)

    echo " status = $status "
done

echo -e "\e[92mFinished deleting old ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} cluster."

echo -e "\e[93mRestoring cluster ${SOURCE_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} to new cluster ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} ..."

CRUSTERRESTORECOMMAND="

aws rds restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time \
--source-db-cluster-identifier $SOURCE_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID \
--db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID \
--restore-type copy-on-write \
--use-latest-restorable-time "

eval $CRUSTERRESTORECOMMAND

status=unknown
while [ "$status" != "available" ]; do
    sleep 10
    status=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --query "*[].{DBClusters:Status}" --output text)
done

echo -e "\e[93mModifying cluster ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} settings..."

CREATECLUSTERCOMMAND="
aws rds modify-db-cluster \
    --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID \
    --master-user-password $NEW_MASTER_PASS \
    --vpc-security-group-ids $SECURITY_GROUP_ID $SECURITY_GROUP_ID_DEV $SECURITY_GROUP_ID_ADMIN \
    --backup-retention-period $BACKUP_RETENTION \
    --apply-immediately "

eval $CREATECLUSTERCOMMAND

status_modify=unknown
while [ "$status_modify" != "available" ]; do
    sleep 10
    status_modify=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --query "*[].{DBClusters:Status}" --output text)

    echo -e "\e[92mModifications to ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} complete."

done

echo " create RDS instance within new cluser ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID}."

CREATEDBCOMMAND="
aws rds create-db-instance \
--db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID \
--db-instance-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID \
--db-instance-class $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_CLASS \
--publicly-accessible
--engine $TARGET_ENGINE "

eval $CREATEDBCOMMAND

# neeed to wait until the new db is in an available state

while [ "${exit_status3}" != "0" ]; do
    echo -e "\e[93mWaiting for ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} to enter 'available' state..."
    aws rds wait db-instance-available --db-instance-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID
    exit_status3="$?"

    INSTANCE_STATUS=$(aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID --query 'DBInstances[0].[DBInstanceStatus]' --output text)
    echo -e "\e[92m${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} is now ${INSTANCE_STATUS}."
    echo -e "\e[92mCreation of ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID} complete."
done

echo -e "\e[92mFinished clone of ${SOURCE_DB_INSTANCE_ID} to ${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID}!"


end=$(date +%s)
runtime=$((end - start))
displaytime=$(displaytime runtime)

echo -e "\e[92mFinished clone of '${SOURCE_DB_INSTANCE_ID}' to '${TARGET_CLUSTER_INSTANCE_ID}"
echo -e "\e[92mThe script took ${displaytime} to run."
exit 0
```

Comment: As I read your solution, I just wanted to let you know there a missing \ in CREATEDBCOMMAND command. Your engine parameter is most likely ommited

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, one important detail, not mentioned and causing me thinking it didn't work, is that not necessarily security policy will be the same, so in order to make the DB available you need to set the the same or appropriate plus make the DB public. I am providing some snippet for Java API:

```
private final AmazonRDS rds;
rds.restoreDBClusterToPointInTime(
        new RestoreDBClusterToPointInTimeRequest()
            .withSourceDBClusterIdentifier("sourceClusterIdentifier")
            .withDBClusterIdentifier("targetName")
            .withRestoreType("copy-on-write")
            .withVpcSecurityGroupIds("vpc_group_id_to_be_found")  //important
            .withUseLatestRestorableTime(true));

DBInstance instanceOfDb = rds.createDBInstance(new CreateDBInstanceRequest()
    .withDBClusterIdentifier("targetName")
    .withDBInstanceIdentifier("targetName-cluster")
    .withEngine("aurora-postgresql")
    .withDBInstanceClass("db.r4.large")
    .withPubliclyAccessible(true) //important
    .withMultiAZ(false)
);

rds.waiters().dBInstanceAvailable()
    .run(new WaiterParameters<>(new DescribeDBInstancesRequest()
        .withDBInstanceIdentifier(instanceOfDb.getDBInstanceIdentifier()))
        .withPollingStrategy(new PollingBuilder().delay(30).maxWait(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()));
```

Comment: Making the DB instance public is not mandatory for cloning, however I can understand if you have such a requirement. Though, I would strongly discourage making any data store public. You should instead move your compute into the private and access the private resources through bastion and ALBs.